# Visual Studio 2012 - Hide folders from solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to hide folder in Visual Studio 2012 solution explorer window? I have multiple folders/files that I don't plan to use and they are just cluttering the interface and it's harder to find things.

It just seems pretty illogical that you can toggle "Show Hidden Files" but you cannot actually hide any files.

## Example

[image]

## Why

WebApi project includes automated help generation that I want to use, however it includes multiple folders that it needs to function. All I care about is Controllers/Models since I'm building the Api itself. But if I delete/remove from project those files than help generator won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Since you want the files to still be accessible, as opposed to just excluding them, you can modify the `csproj` file itself. Unload your project from the solution, right-click and select edit. Scroll down to where your folders are displayed (I tested with a folder called "TestFolder" and a file within it called `TestClass.cs`.

```
<Compile Include="TestFolder\TestClass.cs">        
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Create a new child tag called `Visible` and set the value to `false`.

```
<Compile Include="TestFolder\TestClass.cs">    
    <Visible>false</Visible>    
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Save and reload the project and the files should no longer be visible but accessible. I just did a quick test and it seemed to work fine (but YMMV).

Comment: Good solution but how can I do this on whole folder? Example: `Areas`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure. This is a bit of a hack so there might be a better way of doing it but I can't seem to get an entire folder to be hidden (without resorting to adding tags for each item) :/

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party, but here's a similar solution I just found. I wanted to target all files in all directories inside my "x64" folder (and also hide them. So I used this for the path: "x64\**\*"

Answer (score 4):

Hiding folders is almost certainly a bad idea. Remember that hiding a folder is *not the same* as excluding it from the solution - all hidden items can still be used elsewhere in the code, can be referenced by the build, and get updated when you pull the latest version from source control.

That is the reason why it was never available for project folders - so that people cannot easily confuse their workmates.

Having said that, it is possible to hide folders on the solution level - I guess mostly because it's quite common to have documentation, shared libraries etc on that level. To hide a solution folder, you right click on the folder, and select "Hide Folder" (to unhide, you'd right click *on the solution itself* and select "Unhide folders")

[image]

---

As for your screenshot where you want to hide `Area`, `Scripts` etc - I suspect you're working alone and just started learning MVC - otherwise it wouldn't make sense to hide those folders. They contain legitimate code which is used to run the application. Hiding it is the same as hiding `Program.cs` in a console project for the sole reason that you prefer a smaller tree in the solution.

I do agree that Solution Explorer becomes unmanageable at some point - but instead of messing up with it, I'd recommend to try other tools - Visual Studio ["navigate to"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/02/tips-using-navigate-to-for-search-in-visual-studio.aspx) options or Resharper (I use the latter).

Comment: @andreister - Are you running an add-in of some sort that adds those options? I don't have those options either.

Comment: No addins, but notice I step on the solution, maybe you tried it on a project level? Steve, I updated the answer with more reasoning

Comment: Na man, I want to hide area and scripts because they are needed for help generator. I only work on API myself.

Comment: You may want to update your question and tell why exactly you want to hide those folders, and why simply excluding them is not an option. Not sure I fully understand your comment though

Comment: @andreister Well I added why :)

Comment: Good "Why" section, but still not clear why you want to _hide_ that code. You're working on some part of the project, other people are working on other parts, and each of you should see the whole picture (again, as you say the project doesn't compile when you remove the code, so it's clearly important). Again, if you're concerned about a lengthy Solution Explorer tree you're better off using more advanced navigation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same way in VS 2012, but in VS 2010, I just right click on the folders (and, in some cases, files) that I don't want and exclude them from the solution.

Comment: That is no good because then they won't function. I just want to hide them so I don't see the folders in solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a new feature but you can hide folders from solution explorer without excluding or deleting them.

On VS 2017 (15.5.5)
Just right click on any **solution folder** and click "Hide Folder"