# Project Solution is showing Git Files

Tags: git, visual-studio

The files from Git itself is showing on my Project Explorer and I can't seem to get it out...

[image: as shown here]

what can I do to remove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2012 - Hide folders from solution explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953225/visual-studio-2012-hide-folders-from-solution-explorer)

Comment: In the "Solution Explorer" panel toolbar, you have "Show all files" option enabled. Disable it.

Comment: thanks! that was it

Answer (score 0):

[Project Solution is showing Git Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673269/project-solution-is-showing-git-files?noredirect=1#comment117866512_66673269)

This comment from Philippe solved my problem, for some reason i cant mark it as an answer so here it is